# duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using GTL framework for using google GDrive. I copied all the files from the GTL.xcodeproject into my application after getting failed many times in importing that framework into my application. But still i am getting below mentioned error. I have searched all but found no duplicate files or anything. Please help here.

```
/Users/ashutoshb/Desktop/Screen Shot 2012-11-30 at 10.30.24 AM.png


Ld /Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.app/MowWom normal i386
cd /Users/ashutoshb/Mowwom/MowWomCode/Updated/MowWom
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/ashutoshb/Mowwom/MowWomCode/Updated/MowWom/MowWom/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers" -L/Users/ashutoshb/Mowwom/MowWomCode/Updated/MowWom -  F/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom- dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -  F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks - F/Users/ashutoshb/Mowwom/MowWomCode/Updated/MowWom -filelist  /Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom- dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug- iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/MowWom.LinkFileList -Xlinker - objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.3 -framework SenTestingKit -framework Security -framework MessageUI -lxml2 -lz -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lOAuth -o /Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.app/MowWom


duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLDriveAboutAdditionalRoleInfoItem in:
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDrive_Sources.o
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDriveAbout.o

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLDriveAboutAdditionalRoleInfoItem in:
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDrive_Sources.o
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDriveAbout.o

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLDriveAboutExportFormatsItem in:
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDrive_Sources.o
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDriveAbout.o

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLDriveAboutExportFormatsItem in:
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDrive_Sources.o
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDriveAbout.o

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLDriveAboutFeaturesItem in:
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDrive_Sources.o
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDriveAbout.o

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLDriveAboutFeaturesItem in:
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDrive_Sources.o
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDriveAbout.o

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLDriveAboutImportFormatsItem in:
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDrive_Sources.o
/Users/ashutoshb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MowWom-dmhxeapzkbnuniegdxmsvdgmodrw/Build/Intermediates/MowWom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MowWom.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDriveAbout.o

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLDriveAboutImportFormatsItem in:
```

Answer (score 30):

Make sure you check the "Compile Sources" in your "Build Phases" section as well.  Sometimes they get doubled in there (but appear only once in the project file explorer)

Comment: This also solved my issue. Would have not gotten that if it hadn't been shown here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete all the files/folders from your project location and also remove references from XCode project.

Then, copy library folder to project location and in XCode, click on "Add files ..." and choose the new added folder in project location.