# Google Drive integration error in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, google-drive-api

I created an IPhone app and integrated google drive library into project and have also made the required setting in build setting. I"m getting below error while compiling. Please anyone can help me with this

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
#import "GTLService.h"
#import "GTLQueryDrive.h"
#import "GTLDrive.h"
#import "GDUTILITY.h"


@implementation ViewController



@synthesize authButton; @synthesize addMoreButton; @synthesize
btnRefresh;


@synthesize isAuthorized; @synthesize driveService; @synthesize
driveFiles;






#define kKeychainItemName111 @"GDDEMOTESTERNONARC: Google Drive"

#define kClientId111 @"16458548056-efdl07vmtam1pa159ln9024gc239oted.apps.googleusercontent.com"

#define kClientSecret111 @"yJU-avQu3Y0dlu3tL9ooLDRo"






- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use. }

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.






    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth =[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName111  
clientID:kClientId111  clientSecret:kClientSecret111];

    if ([auth canAuthorize])
    {
        [self isAuthorizedWithAuthentication:auth];
    }




     }



- (GTLServiceDrive *)driveService {
    static GTLServiceDrive *service = nil;

    if (!service)
    {
        service = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];

        // Have the service object set tickets to fetch consecutive pages
        // of the feed so we do not need to manually fetch them.
        service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;

        // Have the service object set tickets to retry temporary error conditions
        // automatically.
        service.retryEnabled = YES;
    }
    return service; }



- (IBAction)authButtonMethos:(id)sender {
    if (!self.isAuthorized) 
    {
        // Sign in.

        SEL finishedSelector = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);

        GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController =[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile clientID:kClientId111
clientSecret:kClientSecret111 keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName111
delegate:self finishedSelector:finishedSelector];      


        [self presentModalViewController:authViewController     animated:YES];
    } 
    else
    {
        // Sign out
        [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch removeAuthFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName111];
        [[self driveService] setAuthorizer:nil];
        //        self.authButton.title = @"Sign in";
        self.isAuthorized = NO;
        //        [self toggleActionButtons:NO];
        [self.driveFiles removeAllObjects];
    }

     }

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth     error:(NSError *)error  {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if (error == nil) 
    {
        [self isAuthorizedWithAuthentication:auth];
    } }


- (void)isAuthorizedWithAuthentication:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth  {
    [[self driveService] setAuthorizer:auth];
    //    self.authButton.title = @"Sign out";
    self.isAuthorized = YES;
    //    [self toggleActionButtons:YES];
    [self loadDriveFiles]; }



- (void)loadDriveFiles  {



    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
    query.q = @"mimeType = 'text/plain'";

    UIAlertView *alert = [GDUTILITY showLoadingMessageWithTitle:@"Loading files"
                                                       delegate:self];
    [self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                              GTLDriveFileList *files,
                                                              NSError *error) 
     {
         [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

         if (error == nil) {
             if (self.driveFiles == nil)
             {
                 self.driveFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             }
             [self.driveFiles removeAllObjects];
             [self.driveFiles addObjectsFromArray:files.items];
             //            [self.tableView reloadData];
         } 
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
             [GDUTILITY showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to load files"
                                          message:[error description]
                                         delegate:self];
         }
     }];

    NSLog(@"Click on the login button");
}
```

I'm running this code on simulator.So I'm getting below error

```
 ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLDriveAbout in
   /Users/bcod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleDDemo-frrwjztsgtylsxbmkifnctrxzjfh/Build/Intermediates/GoogleDDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDDemo.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDriveAbout.o
   and
   /Users/bcod/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleDDemo-frrwjztsgtylsxbmkifnctrxzjfh/Build/Intermediates/GoogleDDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDDemo.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTLDrive_Sources.o
   for architecture i386
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show little bit code..

Comment: You've shown the wrong code.  Start Terminal.app, go to the Source directory and post the output of `$ fgrep GTLDriveAbout *.m`.

Comment: Also, try to check #include usage (in h or m file)... try to remove/comment (step by step) #import "GTLService.h"... "GTLQueryDrive.h".. "GDUTILITY.h"

Answer (score 0):

Multiple reference classes are created in your code.Please remove google api all files and  add again.

Please refer this link,it will help you.

[duplicate symbols for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639411/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386)