# iOS File not found?

Tags: ios, debugging

I was experimenting with what I thought was a minor change in my code involving two of my classes and one function:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AvsAViewController.currentSpec = [[SearchSpecs alloc]init];

    [sender setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Now, the build fails, and I get three errors

```
1) Property 'currentSpec' not found on object of type 'AvsAViewController'


2) Ld /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx normal i386
    cd "/Users/timjones/Desktop/WMDG project/WMDGx"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/WMDGx.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/WMDGx_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx

ld: file not found: /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReportViewController.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


3) GenerateDSYMFile /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app.dSYM /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx
    cd "/Users/timjones/Desktop/WMDG project/WMDGx"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx -o /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app.dSYM

error: unable to open executable '/Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx'
```

Despite the complaint, the property `currentSpec` IS found on object of type `'AvsAViewController'` and the header IS imported.

Now, if I comment out one line:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
//    AvsAViewController.currentSpec = [[SearchSpecs alloc]init];

    [sender setEnabled:NO];
}
```

I get two errors:

```
1) Ld /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx normal i386
    cd "/Users/timjones/Desktop/Where'd My Day Go project/WMDGx"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/WMDGx.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/WMDGx_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx

duplicate symbol _aVsAButton_tag in:
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/AvsAViewController.o
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReportViewController.o
duplicate symbol _cVsCButton_tag in:
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/AvsAViewController.o
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReportViewController.o
duplicate symbol _actVsAllButton_tag in:
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/AvsAViewController.o
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReportViewController.o
duplicate symbol _catVsAllButton_tag in:
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/AvsAViewController.o
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReportViewController.o
duplicate symbol _customDatePickerButton_tag in:
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/AvsAViewController.o
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReportViewController.o
duplicate symbol _goButton_tag in:
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/AvsAViewController.o
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReportViewController.o
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


2) ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


GenerateDSYMFile /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app.dSYM /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx
    cd "/Users/timjones/Desktop/Where'd My Day Go project/WMDGx"
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx -o /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app.dSYM

error: unable to open executable '/Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.app/WMDGx'
```

I've found several similar questions on SO, but the answers seem to be all over the place. I'm painfully aware that my debugging skills need a lot of development, but can someone please give me some specific guidance on this particular problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a clean? Command-Shift-K

Comment: Yes, tried it several times, also tried several builds and Xcode restarts. Just tried all three once again. Same results.

Comment: What is `AvsAViewController` in `AvsAViewController.currentSpec = [[...`?

Comment: It's a class associated with the view to which I'm segueing.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I have the answer - let me pound it out.

Comment: Great! Standing by...

Answer (score 0):

As you figured, this code is the problem:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AvsAViewController.currentSpec = [[SearchSpecs alloc]init];

    [sender setEnabled:NO];
}
```

It's this line:

```
AvsAViewController.currentSpec = [[SearchSpecs alloc]init];
```

You're trying to set a property on a class, when properties can only be set on instances. What you want is the [`destinationViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStoryboardSegue/destinationViewController) property on the `UIStoryboardSegue` you are handed. You probably want your code to look like this:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    segue.destinationViewController.currentSpec = [[SearchSpecs alloc]init];

    [sender setEnabled:NO];
}
```

If Xcode complains about properties not being found, you might need to use casting to tell the compiler to shut up because you know what you're doing:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [(AvsAViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setCurrentSpec:[[SearchSpecs alloc]init]];

    [sender setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Comment: OK, that cleared the problem with the "Property 'currentSpec' not found on object of type 'AvsAViewController'"

Comment: I *think* [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639411/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386) might help - basically, you need to check Compile Sources in Build Phases for duplicate entries.

Comment: I've gone through the list 3 times and find no duplicates.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure. Does the same happen when trying to run on a device?

Comment: Don't have a device. Running on sim. I'm a nooby. And a grateful one, I should add. :)

Comment: OK. I had an Import loop, something I sort of suspected from the outset but didn't know how to track it down. I actually stumbled on it by trial and error. Obviously, I need to learn more about #import and @class directives. Many thanks for your time and guidance, Undo!!!

Comment: Ah... I'd never even heard of an import loop, but it makes sense. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your linker error.

duplicate symbol **_actVsAllButton_tag** in:
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/**AvsAViewController.o**
    /Users/timjones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMDGx-dixcfloqnhryzreowrpbowempliz/Build/Intermediates/WMDGx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMDGx.build/Objects-normal/i386/**ReportViewController.o**

Just read what it says.

You have a symbol named _actVsAllButton_tag in AvsAViewController.m and a symbol with the exact same name in ReportViewController.m.

Plus half a dozen other duplicates.

Here's a tip to solve many problems: Don't say "I go these errors, I don't know why". Say to yourself "There is an error in my code. Which error is it"? Then you look at the error messages and read what they say.

Comment: I probably should have enshrined my solution in an answer, along with the details, but I did note in a comment to the first answerer that I had discovered a header file import loop, which accounted for the duplicate symbols. Your suggestion is relevant and appreciated. Thanks!